# How to get Invoice Payment amount - Custom Report

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I'm creating a custom report in the Invoice module.

```
<span class="text-nowrap" t-esc="doc.invoice_payments_widget" />
```

I added the above code and it returns jSON format. But I need to get the **amount** only.

```
{"title": "Less Payment", "outstanding": false, "content": [{"name": "Customer Payment: INV/2021/0006", "journal_name": "Bank", "amount": 500.0, "currency": "$", "digits": [69, 2], "position": "before", "date": "2021-03-26", "payment_id": 25, "account_payment_id": 2, "payment_method_name": "Manual", "move_id": 11, "ref": "BNK1/2021/0002 (INV/2021/0006)"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be more than one payment so you should sum up all amounts of the `content` dictionary.

```py
sum([content.get('amount', 0.0)
    for content in doc.invoice_payments_widget.get('content', [])])
```

I would write a method for it, bind that to the report and call it. It would be more clean, too.

Comment: I'm just new to Odoo development. Where should I put that? :)

Comment: in your `t-esc`

Answer (score 1):

If you get back json, you first need to convert it to a Python structure using the json library:

```
import json

data = json.loads('{"title": "Less Payment", "outstanding": false, "content": [{"name": "Customer Payment: INV/2021/0006", "journal_name": "Bank", "amount": 500.0, "currency": "$", "digits": [69, 2], "position": "before", "date": "2021-03-26", "payment_id": 25, "account_payment_id": 2, "payment_method_name": "Manual", "move_id": 11, "ref": "BNK1/2021/0002 (INV/2021/0006)"}]}')
```

And from there you can use standard code such as [CZoellner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813331/14578331) suggested. If you do not understand that answer, you can look up "list comprehension" for Python.

Comment: I guess our answers aren't enough, because the environment is QWeb/XML. And there is no good documentation or tutorial about binding methods to reports as far as i know. But good hint! I just overlooked "JSON".